# Can I compile an Area and use the dll as a module for multiple sites?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I am trying to find out if I am thinking about this correctly. My goal is to be drop in a dll and have access to helpers, and partial views (Maybe Views too), using an MVC pattern. I have been treating Areas as modules lately using @RenderAction to serve me up some partials when I need them anywhere on a site. I can copy that whole area out and reuse it on another site, but that means changing namespaces on each file and it's duplication of the area so I am not getting to update it in one place for all sites. I am open to ideas and thoughts if I am approaching this incorrectly. For clarity's sake, here is my question: Is there a way to isolate only an area and compile it in it's own assembly? If so why is there not a new project type for that? Like add->new->module?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may checkout the [following article](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/) which illustrates a nice technique allowing you to embed razor views into a separate assembly as embedded resources.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This does seem like it could help me get started, but I was hoping for a simpler solution. Also I don't want to lose the MVC structure of an area. How do people implement reusable modules?

Comment: @user506016, currently there is nothing built-in. I think in future versions of ASP.NET MVC there will be an out of the box solution. Until then you are on your own to implement it by using a custom `VirtualPathProvider`. And what you see in the blog post is a great simplification over what you would have had to do in order to implement it manually.